# Turn off access logger in go-json-rest

Tags: rest, logging, go

I am trying to write REST services in Go. As there are different frameworks for writing REST service in Go, we would like to do some performance testing before choosing the framework.

Currently I did a sample using [go-json-rest](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest). 
But when I execute this sample REST request, I see the following logs printed in my terminal.

```
24/Nov/2015:12:30:35 +0530 200 29μs "GET /countries HTTP/1.1" - "Java/1.8.0_45"
```

This logging will take some time and impact my performance report. 
How can I switch of this logging?

Comment: I'd guess you are using the `DefaultDevStack`. Maybe reading the whole documentation for go-json-rest would be helpful?

Comment: Yes I am using DefaultDevStack and I did a quick look into the documentation and didn't find the information :(

Comment: Take a look at what the DefaultDevStack contains and you'll see.

Comment: Got it. I have to use DefaultCommonStack. Could you please add it as answer?

Comment: Sometimes, dive  into the source code would be a better way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that it's [AccessLogApacheMiddleware](https://godoc.org/github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest#AccessLogApacheMiddleware) that controls your logging, and `DefaultDevStack` [contains](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/blob/master/rest/api.go#L52) the `AccessLogApacheMiddleware`.

Two ways to prevent logging:

1. You can use a predefined variable like [DefaultCommonStack](https://github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/blob/master/rest/api.go#L78) which doesn't contain the `AccessLogApacheMiddleware`;
2. Construct your own `...Middlewares`. Since the [Use](https://godoc.org/github.com/ant0ine/go-json-rest/rest#Api.Use) function is a `Variadic Functions`, which pass the multiple middlewares into the function. If you don't need `AccessLogApacheMiddleware`, you just ignore it. It gives you more power to control whatever middlewares you like.

e.g.

```
api := rest.NewApi()
api.Use(&rest.TimerMiddleware{},
    &rest.RecorderMiddleware{},
    &rest.PoweredByMiddleware{},
    &rest.RecoverMiddleware{})
```

May this be helpful.